# Randomly started to get 400 "Invalid request" error: "The provided encoding is not supported."

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Starting around 00:10 UTC on Saturday 30th Jan 2021 we've started to see some of our cron jobs that update Microsoft shared calendar entries randomly return a 400 with the following error in the returned JSON contents:

```
'{ "error": { "code": "invalidRequest", "message": "The provided encoding is not supported." } }',
```

These appear randomly - if I rerun the command that created it there a good chance it will work just fine.  Our cron job runs every hour (it's maintaining a share calendar of approved changes from our change management system) and the events it fails on appear to be different on every run.

Has something changed with Graph API over the weekend or are Microsoft's server experiencing heavy load?  This seems like a really weird error message to get from an overloaded service though - I've gone down the rabbit hole of trying to work out what encoding it's talking about without any luck (especially as debugging is tricky because re-running calendar entry scripts by hand often works!).  Searching for 'Microsoft Graph API "The provided encoding is not supported"' hasn't really thrown much up either so I'm a bit stumped now. Ideas anyone?

EDIT: The request is being made from a Perl script using LWP to PATCH to the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user-id>/calendars/<calendar-id>`. Here's an example of the dump of the object structure when we get the error (with the bearer key deleted obviously!). This contains everything being sent and everything being returned:

```
[69295] [Mon Feb  1 08:10:07 2021] [warning]: Event creation failed. LWP UA response object:
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 '_protocol' => 'HTTP/1.1',
                 '_content' => '{ "error": { "code": "invalidRequest", "message": "The provided encoding is not supported." } }',
                 '_rc' => 400,
                 '_headers' => bless( {
                                        'connection' => 'close',
                                        'client-response-num' => 1,
                                        'date' => 'Mon, 01 Feb 2021 08:10:07 GMT',
                                        'client-ssl-cert-issuer' => '/C=US/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Azure TLS Issuing CA 01',
                                        'client-ssl-cipher' => 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256',
                                        'client-peer' => '20.190.169.24:443',
                                        'strict-transport-security' => 'max-age=31536000',
                                        'content-length' => '95',
                                        '::std_case' => {
                                                          'client-response-num' => 'Client-Response-Num',
                                                          'client-ssl-cert-issuer' => 'Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer',
                                                          'client-ssl-cipher' => 'Client-SSL-Cipher',
                                                          'client-peer' => 'Client-Peer',
                                                          'strict-transport-security' => 'Strict-Transport-Security',
                                                          'client-date' => 'Client-Date',
                                                          'client-ssl-cert-subject' => 'Client-SSL-Cert-Subject',
                                                          'client-ssl-socket-class' => 'Client-SSL-Socket-Class'
                                                        },
                                        'client-date' => 'Mon, 01 Feb 2021 08:10:07 GMT',
                                        'content-type' => 'application/json',
                                        'client-ssl-cert-subject' => '/C=US/ST=WA/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=graph.microsoft.com',
                                        'client-ssl-socket-class' => 'IO::Socket::SSL'
                                      }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
                 '_msg' => 'Bad Request',
                 '_request' => bless( {
                                        '_content' => '{"extensions":[{"@odata.type":"Microsoft.Graph.OpenTypeExtension","RTTicketId":"236595","extensionName":"uk.ac.lboro.lunet.RTTicketId"}],"body":{"content":"<a href=\'https://servicedesk.lboro.ac.uk/Changes/Normal.html?id=236595\'>Change details in RT</a>.<br><br><h2>Test</h2><h3>Risk Level: Low</h3>","contentType":"HTML"},"singleValueExtendedProperties":[{"value":"236595","id":"String {E6F70170-9BED-11E8-8CBC-CDC132C02D95} Name RTTicketId"}],"subject":"RT Ticket# 236595 Test (Drafting (draft))","showAs":"tentative","end":{"timeZone":"UTC","dateTime":"2021-01-29 17:00:00"},"start":{"timeZone":"UTC","dateTime":"2021-01-29 07:00:00"}}',
                                        '_uri' => bless( do{\(my $o = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/8c0729fb-fdd8-4c47-afdd-6319d7f53527/calendars/AAMkADcyNzFmM2NmLTQwNWUtNDdkYi05NjBkLTMyY2Y0YWZmNjNjOABGAAAAAADLxa7s4pdTQYKigJvn9tIVBwCQ07ZtjCb-RJqL4KgdwIpWAAAA2V50AABdqLP0L9GOTKSkX7kyfyLXACFn_IIFAAA=/events/AAMkADcyNzFmM2NmLTQwNWUtNDdkYi05NjBkLTMyY2Y0YWZmNjNjOABGAAAAAADLxa7s4pdTQYKigJvn9tIVBwCQ07ZtjCb-RJqL4KgdwIpWAAAA2V53AACCh71i_SZfT6deBOa2tmDIAAW36HLpAAA=')}, 'URI::https' ),
                                        '_headers' => bless( {
                                                               'user-agent' => 'libwww-perl/6.49',
                                                               'content-type' => 'application/json; charset=utf8',
                                                               '::std_case' => {
                                                                                 'if-ssl-cert-subject' => 'If-SSL-Cert-Subject'
                                                                               },
                                                               'authorization' => 'Bearer <deleted>'
                                                             }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
                                        '_method' => 'PATCH',
                                        '_uri_canonical' => $VAR1->{'_request'}{'_uri'}
                                      }, 'HTTP::Request' )
               },
```

Comment: What is the graph API call that you are making? You can test the same in [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge).

Comment: Share the Graph API call & the detailed response (contains the requestid, timestamp) as @ShivaKeshavVarma asked so that we can help. Try isolate the issue out of your code using Graph Explorer or POSTMAN

Comment: I've edited the original post with the requested  information (it was too long to add as a comment here). As I said, the code has been working for months, and this just started to appear randomly early on Saturday morning.

Comment: hmm, interestingly i ran the above Graph API call in Graph Explorer/POSTMAN and it works for me!!

Comment: Yes, it works for me most of the time too - that's the point. It just happens to fail randomly with different entries which then subsequently work again.  If there's no obvious infrastructure changes happened in your cloud on Friday/Saturday night, could you tell me what the error message indicates is wrong, or is it the wrong error message (and should be an overloaded or similar?)

Comment: And strangely, things now seem to be magically working again. I assume whatever infrastructure was broken in the cloud has been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue, but executed a totally different Graph call: My call creates a Microsoft Team and has been successfully working for years... For the last few days, it randomly fails with the same error Jon mentioned.

I made sure that the JSON which is sent as the Payload of the Graph request always gets serialized as UTF-8 encoded string... Even that I cannot be sure that this fixed the issue, I didn't observe errors since then...

Comment: Thank you - I was beginning to think it was something just affecting my code!  The payload I'm sending in is pretty much the plain ASCII subset of UTF-8, and I've already got the charset encoding set for UTF-8 on the request just in case any accented characters do appear.